# Marker Clustering with Cordova Google Map

Tags: google-maps, cordova-plugins

Is it possible for us to create marker clustering with Cordova Google Map plugin that will work on both Android and iOS? If yes, how can it be done?

Comment: https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/issues/1534

https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/issues/1006

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of the Cordova Google Map plugin.
Development of the marker clustering is on the way.
But some people already implement it in JS.

If you want to try to implement by yourself, check out the marker cluster code for the Google Maps JavaScript API v3.
Basic idea is the same.

https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/blob/gh-pages/src/markerclusterer.js

Comment: Thanks a lot for your respond and answer. The road-map image on github shows for new user use v2.0-beta2 and now the latest ionic native also use v2 map.  I wanna to ask, is v2.0 is now safe for production use? If yes, then I'm gonna to switch and start using it. Thank you.

Comment: Lots of developers uses the v2 as production. If you face any trouble, please let me know at the github issue list. I will support it.